# Google map v2 to v3 code

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am working on a migration project from google maps V2 to V3 and wrote the bellow code but
getting error and unable to solve the problem.

Am i using wrong method of google maps?

What is wrong in this code?

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 225px; font-family:arial; font-size:10px;"></div>
<?php
$map = getMap();
echo $map = str_replace('$_ADDRESS', 'MYADDRESS', $map );


function getMap()
{
    $mapKey = 'MYKEY';
    $_script = '
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='. $mapKey .'&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            var map = null;
            var geocoder = null;

            // call initialize function
            initialize( $_ADDRESS );

            // initialize map

            function initialize() 
            {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });             
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                // call show Address
                showAddress( address );
            }

            // show address
            function showAddress(address)
            {
                if (geocoder)
                {
                    geocoder.getPosition( address, function(point)
                    {
                        if (!point)
                        {
                            alert(address + " not found");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            map.setCenter(point, 13);
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(point);
                            map.addOverlay(marker);
                            //marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            //]]>
    </script>';
    return $_script;
}
?>
```

Any idesa?
Thanks

Comment: What error are you receiving? And what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @karl-johab: no error with blank page

Comment: When you say blank page, if you "view source", what do you see.  One would presume that the script is there..?

Comment: @karl-johab:In view source i am getting no error. it is showing js, html code that is written in php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have split these answers as the first deals with the fundamentals of the javascript, this then deals with using the Google Maps API.

As I've never used the maps API, I can't comment on V2, but looking at how you do things in V3, I think this does what you're looking for...

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 225px; font-family:arial; font-size:10px;"></div>
<?php
$map = getMap();
echo $map = str_replace('$_ADDRESS', 'MYADDRESS', $map );


function getMap()
{
    $mapKey = 'MYKEY';
    $_script = '
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            var map = null;
            var geocoder = null;

            // call initialize function
            initialize( "$_ADDRESS" );

            // initialize map
            function initialize( address ) 
            {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });             
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                // call show Address
                showAddress( address );
            }

            // show address
            function showAddress(address)
            {
                if (geocoder)
                {
                    geocoder.geocode( { "address": address }, function( results, status )
                    {
                        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK )
                        {
                            position = results[0].geometry.location;
                            map.setCenter(position, 13);
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: position });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert(address + " not found");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            //]]>
    </script>';
    return $_script;
}
?>
```

Having said that, I'd question the str_replace straight into the javascript - can you trust the source of that data?  If not, then you should look up how to sanitise that string before you put it into your javascript or you may allow people to inject code into your site.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the fundamental javascript issues you have...

Try adding quotes around the string that you're replacing into the javascript

```
echo $map = str_replace('$_ADDRESS', 'MYADDRESS', $map );
```

Becomes:

```
echo $map = str_replace('$_ADDRESS', "'MYADDRESS'", $map );
```

That way the string that contains the address in javascript is properly quoted.

Also, ensure that you can receive the address in your initialize function:

```
function initialize()
```

Becomes:

```
function initialize( address )
```

Finally, do not redeclare "map" when you assign it a value in "initialize", otherwise you are referencing a different variable that only exists in that function:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
```

Becomes:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
```

Comment: Just spotted that you pass MYADDRESS into the initialize function, but that function does not have any parameters.  You then pass address into showAddress, but that variable is never set.

Comment: now i changed that line: function initialize(address) and also getting address value within initialize and showAddress functions but again not changing address.
am i using wrong method of google maps in showAddress function?

Comment: I have to admit, I'd never used the maps API, so I had to have a look around to see what needed doing.  But the last point on the basic javascript issues that you have is that the "map" variable that you reference inside initialize is different to the one you reference in showAddress.  I.E. you redeclared it with a 'var'.  I've edited my answer to reflect that